# Google Sheets Query Dynamic Rance with Multiple Conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am presented with the following challenge:

Is it possible to create a query function with multiple dynamic ranges?

I want to average the data in one column based on a few conditions. Normally I would use averageifs but the problem is that the columns may change positions so I cannot use a static reference like column A. I found a way to incorporate dynamic range into the query function but only for 1 condition.

Standard syntax:
"Average column A if column B contains"

I require it to work like this:
"Average the column with title 'Score' if the column with title 'Type' contains"

Here is a link to the file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kjcWAZpXfIh85BbkS6_CtwleDj8h43xk-oHF9FqZOHc/edit?usp=sharing

If you are wondering why the columns change, it's because the file is being used by multiple people and whey download different csv files.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(FILTER('Raw Data'!A2:1000, REGEXMATCH('Raw Data'!1:1, "Score|Type")), 
 "select avg(Col1) where Col2 = 'Main' label avg(Col1)''")
```

[image]